# Any functioning system for interactive proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, proof-of-work

My problem is to outsource an array of data and ask the prover to sort the data.

I am wonder if there is any working system out there that support interactive proof for the above computation? Or if none, any particular protocol that may be efficient enough and implementable for the problem of verifiable sorting?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details on which application you have in mind? Do you want to outsource plain data for sorting and then get the data back (the other party should just do the sorting for you)? Is the data collected somewhere and you want to be sure that it is sorted when you retrieve it?

Comment: Alternatively, is the comparison operator a secret that has been [committed to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme)? $\hspace{1.61 in}$

Comment: @Richard You may have a look at [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/138316/submitted-crypto-2010-camera-ready.pdf) and there is also some work on sorting fully homomorphic encrypted data [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-03515-4_17).